# vuejs not working on the vps

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vps

the initialized app using [`vue init webpack my-project`] compiles successufly on the vps but when visiting `servername:8080` it renders nothing, the terminal log:
    `DONE  Compiled successfully in 3245ms`

> Listening at http://localhost:8080

```
(node:23617) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 3
(node:23617) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are 
not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit 
code.
```

the browser console shows this error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH app.js`

thanks in progress :)

Comment: Is 8080 port opened in your vps?  Did you tried with http://<ip>:8080?

Comment: you coud try checking your browserSync.server conifg for your default port
if it is 8080 or not.